# How can i get the value (as in displayed value not value="") of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a select and i am trying to retrieve the displayed value of current selected option and i don't mean mean the value="" or `.val()`
let say this is my select

```
<select id="name" >
<option value="">select all</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Text 1</option>
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
<option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

lets say i am trying to retrieve the selected value of the current selected "Text 1"

I've tried

```
$('#name').text();
```

But this returns the text of all 4 options.

is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
$("#name > option:selected").text();
```

Or in pure JavaScript:

```
var selEl   = ​document.getElementById("name")​​,
    selText = selEl.options[selEl.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

console.log(selText);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('option:selected', '#name').text();
```

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - realized that within seconds, changed it!

Comment: Is using the context selector actually noticably faster than just using a descendant selector?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using JQuery. You should just be able to do:

```
$("#name").children("[selected]").text();
```

Comment: Are you sure the attribute selector will reflect the `selected` property, not the initial state?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CsLX9/7/
That took far longer to setup than it should. It was giving me trouble, so I just stuck the JS inline on an onclick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `$($('#name')[0].options[$('#name')[0].selectedIndex]).text();` should give you what you want. At least, if you drop the `.text` bit, it returns a jQuery object referencing the selected option node

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate its `.selectedIndex` property like this:

```
var node = document.getElementById( 'name' ), val;

node.onchange = function() {

    val = this[ this.selectedIndex ].value;

};
```

`val` will hold the `value` of the element that is currently selected.